# I'm having trouble getting Apache to run properly on my Mac so I can use localhost to view my company's website files on my computer

Tags: macos, apache, web, server

I've looked all around the web and can't find anything out. I've tried editing the port in the httpd.conf file, and MySQL is running fine, but when I try starting Apache, it doesn't start at all.

Here's what I've tried in my Mac terminal:

```
jeremygallen@Jeremys-iMac ~ % sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start
Starting XAMPP for Mac OS X 8.2.4-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
jeremygallen@Jeremys-iMac ~ % sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp stop
Stopping XAMPP for Mac OS X 8.2.4-0...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...not running.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...ok.
jeremygallen@Jeremys-iMac ~ % sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start
Starting XAMPP for Mac OS X 8.2.4-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

Comment: Sounds like any other web server is already running, as indicated by the error message. What have you tried to resolve that?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and notice that this question, as you phrase it, is not about programming ([help/on-topic]), doesn't give detailed information ([ask]): "I've tried editing" is far from a proper description. Also, the error message _"Another web server is already running."_ is quite clear, and without knowing more details, all we can do is to ask you to stop that other webserver.

Comment: I don't know how to stop a web server on Mac so that I can start another. I've tried doing this, but the MySQL and Apache servers won't start on XAMPP when I try starting them in that case.

Comment: I can't start Apache on my Mac even though the ports I'm trying to start them on are empty. It says "I don't have enough privileges" even though I'm clearly the owner of my computer.